# How to check existence of an ActiveRecord from a query without iterating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model `Item` with attributes `attr1`, `attr2` and `attr3`.

Given a collection of `Item` models (e.g. from `Item.all`), how would I check if there exists an item with `attr1 == value1`, `attr2 == value2` and `attr3 == value3` **without** having to iterate through all the items or performing another query?

Comment: If you want to check them in memory, you'd have to iterate, no way around that. Ruby does have `find` and `select` methods on array to make that easier

Comment: Technically, it may not iterate through _all of the items in the list_. If you use `Array#find` (or `detect` or `any?`), it will stop iterating at first element found. Example: `(1..5).to_a.any? { |i| puts i ; i == 3 }` => it stops iterating once `i == 3` is true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an algorithms perspective, you can't search an unsorted list faster than O(n). So iterating through your collection is the best way to search your collection.

Comment: Yep, that's 100% correct. I guess I'm wondering if Rails' ActiveRecord data structure has something under the hood that allows for faster access.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I think the tools that ruby and rails give you are for coding convenience rather than speed optimizations

Answer (score 2):

If you have already all items assign to an variable `items` then you can just use [`find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) (or `detect`) to search for a matching record in that list without performing another query:

```
items.find { |item| item.attr1 == value1 && item.attr2 == value2 && item.attr3 == value3 w }
```

Note: `find` returns the first matching record when found, `nil` otherwise.

Comment: This is how I am currently doing it. However, the documentation says that it is iterating through each element, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: But you cannot avoid this. How can you check if a specific element is in a list of elements without checking all elements in that list? That might change if you were able to preprocess the list in some way (filtering or sorting). But when you start with  just something like `items = Item.all` there is no other way but checking against all items in the list.

Comment: For an unsorted array this is true, but I'm not sure if a collection of Rails' ActiveRecord data structure behaves exactly like an array.

Comment: After all records were loaded from an `ActiveRecord::Relation` they are just stored in an "ordinary" array. That said: No, there is no magic that can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ActiveRecord::Relation#any?](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-any-3F)

```
Item.where(attr1: value1, attr2: value2, attr3: value3).any?
```

If you already have an ActiveRecord relation object, you can still use this approach.  For example if you have this in your controller:

```
def index
  @items = Item.all
end
```

You can do this in your view or wherever:

```
@items.where(attr1: value1, attr2: value2, attr3: value3).any?
```

Comment: I tried this on the rails console and it performs another query. I want to be able to check the models already pulled into memory.

Comment: please post example of your code. I don't know what you mean by "already pulled into memory"

Comment: e.g. I am trying to check existence of an item in `items = Item.all()`

Comment: It's still performing a query when I try it in the console.

Comment: @DanielChen you need to decide what's more important and WHEN to hit the database and when to use ruby. Depending on the size of your database, it may be more efficient to use the solution I've provided.  If the number of items in the collection are small, then you can use the answer provided below.  You can't avoid 2 calls of some kind unless you do the filtered query BEFORE you instatiat the collection object.